# Is it possible to force boost-build adding subproject's include-path into main project?

Tags: c++, boost, bjam, boost-build

I have made bjam file for a subproject. This subproject contains some sources and headers.
The result of building is a static library. I want to use this subproject from another project. Is there a way to avoid specifying path to subproject headers explicitly?

For example:

```
# Jamfile for sub-library
project sublib
     : requirements <include>../headers/include
     : source-location ../ ;

lib sublib : [ glob src/*.cpp ] : <link>static ;
```

I want boost-build to add "../headers/include" from the above into the next jam-file automatically. But right now I need to specify it explicitly

```
# Jamfile for my root project
use-project /sublib  : path_to_sublib/sublib-folder ;

project rootproject
: requirements <include>root_project_headers/
               <include>path_to_sublib/headers/include/ # explicit declaration
               <library>//sublib
               <define>_VARIADIC_MAX=10
     : source-location ../../ ;

exe root-executable : [ glob src/*.cpp ] ;
```

Is it possible? These jam-files are simplified here from my original ones. And these files work to me.

P.S. I found usage-requirements property in documentation but I didn't find a way to make it work. I tried all variants I could imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Subproject Jamfile

```
 lib subproj
    : subproj.cpp
    : <include>.
      <link>static
    :
    : <include>.
    ;
```

Project Jamfile

```
exe proj
    : <source files>
      /subproj//subproj
    ;
```

works for me.